# Square root of a positive fraction gives complex number in Python

Tags: python-3.x, complex-numbers, square-root

Consider this example-
`(-25.0000001**2)**(1/2)`

This returns-

> Python 3.8.3

> (1.5308085050574255e-15+25.0000001j)

Now I expected some tiny errors. But this looks like a complex number. What does this mean?

Does python simply use the complex representation to describe numbers with very tiny decimals?

Also, I know that this is hugely inefficient but just to test the limits.

Comment: I bet -1**2 is -1 and not 1 like you wanted

Comment: I see. Recalled the precedence rules from C and Java where we don't have ** operator. Led me to believe negation has the highest precedence amongst all arithmetic operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just a side-effect of [Python Operator Precedence](https://thehelloworldprogram.com/python/python-operators-order-precedence/), you'll realize that

```
>>> -25**2
-625
>>> (-25)**2
625
```

Since the exponentian (**) is given precedence over negative(-) the result comes out to be -625. which square rooted gives you that complex number.
You should be doing this instead:

```
>>> ((-25.0000001)**2)**(1/2)
25.0000001
```